# While editing a word file with python-docx and saving, it close. all the other word files as well

Tags: ms-word, python-docx

I have done some coding to replace words in a certain paragraph, but when the save command is run, it closes all the other word files that are open. I wonder how to avoid closing other Word files.

My code is given below:

```py
    import docx
    doc = docx.Document()
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if 'old_word' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('old_word', 'new_word')
    doc.save('path/to/save/modified_document.docx')
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if 'old_word' in paragraph.text:
    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('old_word', 'new_word')
```

should be

```py
if 'old_word' in paragraph.Range.text:
    paragraph.text = paragraph.Range.text.replace('old_word', 'new_word')
```

I think there is a mistake in your code that caused the **crash, not closing other files**. Cause the **[Paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph)** object doesn't have **[Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.text)** property, [**Range**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.range) has.

Comment: @jonsson yes, if I was wrong, plz downvote me. Thank you very much.